# Recursive WinDBG script does not work

Tags: recursion, windbg

I have the following recursive WinDBG script:

```
.if ($sicmp("${$arg1}", "-n") != 0)
{
    r @$t0 = ${$arg1}
}
.if (@$t0)
{
    r @$t1 = wo(@$t0+0x18)
    .foreach /pS1 /ps1 (x {dq /c1 poi(@$t0+8)+0x10 L@$t1})
    { 
        .echo x
        r @$t2 = x
        .push /r /q
        r @$t0 = poi(@$t2+0x28)
        $$>a< ${$arg0} -n
        .pop /r /q
    }
}
```

The code is inspired by an example here - http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2013/07/25/displaying-and-searching-stdmap-contents-in-windbg/#comment-2829748

The problem is that I cannot invoke `$$>a< ${$arg0} -n` from within the `.foreach` body - it fails with **Alias already defined** error.

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: Do you really want to script it that way? No chance of getting PyKd up and running?

Comment: Right now - yes. As for PyKd - maybe later.

Comment: I have more problems. The graph I am exploring contains cyclic references, so in order to count the nodes I need to cache the visited once (I do not want to modify the memory of the nodes themselves). No idea how to do it in pure WinDBG. So, I am willing to try PyKd, but scared of the setup. Any pointers?

Comment: I have problems with pykd. It does not recognize the installed version. Instead, it seems to find the python27.dll in TortoiseHg, which is, my guess, 32 bits. Trying to run the python REPL kills WinDBG immediately.

Comment: I have that situation on my Win7 PC as well and it's quite hard to figure out what the reason is. The PyKd team has shown interest to investigate this, but I could not provide enough information.

Comment: is the script trying to dump some member of std::map as linked or is this something else can you comment your script with actual inputs

Comment: 1) About pykd setup: do you try pykd_bootstrap 2.0 to run python in windb? this is recommended and only supported way to run pykd. Try to call !pykd.info - this command lists all python which pykd can use.
2) You can use JScript with windbg 10.0.15063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the **.foreach** command. I have rewritten the script using **.for** and it works fine:

```
.if ($sicmp("${$arg1}", "-n") != 0)
{
    r @$t0 = ${$arg1}
}
.if (@$t0)
{
    r @$t1 = wo(@$t0+0x18)
    .for (r @$t2 = 0; @$t2 < @$t1; r @$t2 = @$t2 + 1)
    {
        r @$t3 = poi(poi(@$t0+8)+(0x10 + @$t2 * 8))
        .printf "%p\n", @$t3
        .push /r /q
        r @$t0 = poi(@$t3+0x28)
        $$>a< ${$arg0} -n
        .pop /r /q
    }
}
```

So the answer is - use `.for`, if you can.